# What PHP Twitter OAuth libraries are available? Which one should I use?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

Twitter lists the PHP Libraries below on their developer site. I'm working my way through their code, but I wanted to get some feedback from the community of experts.

1. Are there others which are newer / better?
2. Which one is the most widely used?
3. What are the advantages and disadvantages for each?

- [Oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) *by Corollarium Technologies* – an OAuth library for clients and providers
- [Services_Twitter (PEAR)](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Twitter) *by Joe Stump, David Jean Louis and Bill Shupp* – a Twitter API library
- **[TmhOAuth](http://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth)** *by Matt Harris* – an OAuth library (supports file uploading)
- [TwitterOAuth](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) *by Abraham Williams* – a Twitter API library
- [Twitter async](http://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/tree/master) *by Jaisen Mathai* – a wrapper for Twitter OAuth API (provides asynchronous calls)

Notes: I know the *"Which one should I use?"* part of the question title is subjective, but I think the question body asks in a more objective way and the title seemed better shorter.

I will upvote all helpful / useful answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Abraham's TwitterOAuth library and find it to be quite good. It comes with some good working example pages that go through the OAuth dance, and provides you with a simple TwitterOAuth object that has methods like `get` and `post`.

```
// $connection is the instantiated TwitterOAuth object
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Hello, World!', 'in_reply_to_status_id' => 123456));
$tweets = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline', array('include_entities' => true));
```

I can't comment on the other libraries, as I haven't used them - but then I haven't needed to either ;)

Comment: And feel free to hit me up on Twitter, @[abraham](https://twitter.com/abraham), if you have any questions about TwitterOAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Not a person from PHP field but yes have used quite a lot oAuth system for our application.But in my opinion you are the best person to decide which one to use as you have already mentioned in your question (*I know the "Which one should I use?"* )

the reason for my point is.

1. Every individual person has his/her own way to analyze the given API.
2. Each API can be best fit in some use cases while on others it will not be best choice.
3. Sometime we tend to use some API's which are fancy or being told by many people that they are really working great but it end we find that we have more than what we want/require.
4. Which one is widely used is not always a criteria that it is best for our use case.

My best bet is to analyze your requirements and than do a check which one best fit in your needs and than you can always ask if that is a good choice (provide your requirement also).

So in end answer is with you as requirement are with you :)